# Retrieve confidence value Yolov5

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I'm using this code to load the yolov5 model `model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', 'C:\Object Detection\yolov5_object_detection\last.pt')` and how can I retrieve the confidence value after the model detected on an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the model, feed an image to it, loop through the predictions and extract their contents.

```py
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', pretrained=True)
model.eval()
det = model(img)  # feed image

for *xyxy, conf, cls in det:  # loop through results and extract contents
    print(*xyxy)
    print(conf)   # what you are looking for
    print(cls)
```